# RISC 32I Jump and Branch LSB hard wired to zero

Tags: assembly, riscv

Referring to RV32I we make LSB of Branch and Jump instruction as hard wired to zero to extend the address range in instruction's immediate field, as we have word align memory there must be two zeros in the LSBs, now my question is that what if we hard wire last two bits in Jump and Branch instruction's immediate so we have a address range x4, instead of shifting the 32 bits after sign extend in immediate geneartion section.

Answer (score 4):

It would work, and in fact, MIPS, a RISC V predecessor does this.

However, RISC V is designed to allow a compact instruction format (RVC), which allows for 16-bit instructions.  In fact, RISC V allows instruction extensions that can have instructions that are multiples of 16-bits (16, 32, 48, 64, 80, 96, ...).

In order to allow tooling to work across flavors of RISC V that support only 32-bit instructions and also those that support instructions that are multiples of 16-bits, the designers chose to hardwire only one bit to zero, not 2 bits.

This means, for example, that a library might be complied to RV32I and still work properly on hardware that has the RVC extension and mixes use of RVC and that library in the same process (and same thread / call chain).